# How to use JSONB with Ruby Geocoder in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

My latitude and longitude columns are inside a JSONB type column named `geographic`, like this:

```
geographic: {
  coordinates: [0, 0],
}
```

In Geocoder config I need to set column names (`geocoded_by :address, latitude: :lat, longitude: :long`) to use methods like `nearbys`, but Geocoder do not recognize JSONB type columns.

Comment: have you tried to add methods to your model `def lat # to return extracted from json latitude` and `def long # to return longitude` ? :lat and :long are just column names

Comment: @SergiiBrytiuk yep! Thanks for comment :)